# Word 2013 add-in ribbon bar

Tags: office-addins

We have a Word-addin configured in Word 2016 and found the new option in Menu bar and Ribbon bar display properly, but when configuring the same manifest xml in word 2013, the add-in is loaded on document but the menu and ribbon bar are not displayed. Can some one suggest whats the difference and if something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Ribbon tabs are supported from Office for Windows Desktop 2016 (build 16.0.6769+) onwards. So custom menu will not be displayed for office 2013

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands